# How can I hide text content but not child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with an html feed that gives me the following structure

```
<div class="a">
    <span class="b">Some Text</span>
    Some other, redundant text
</div>
```

I can't change the structure of the html feed, but I was wondering if there is a CSS solution that will hide the redundant text, so that it takes up zero space, while still keeping the `<span>` element visible.

Comment: The text is called a "text node". Unfortunately, I don't think you can select text nodes in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hacky but works

```css
.a {
  font-size: 0px;
}
.a span {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

don't use `visibility` property, it makes the text invisible but does not remove it.

Answer (score 3):

```css
div > span {
  visibility: visible; 
}

div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <span class="b">Some Text</span>
    Some other, redundant text
</div>
```